# Return True/False Boolean to http request

Tags: php, web-services, function, return

I am working with a 3rd party API that is sending $_POST data via http and all they are expecting back is a True or False.

Question: I know I can echo the string true or false but is it possible to return the value similar to how a function returns? Also if false I am going to send an error message to the screen via echo or print. Will that affect the Boolean being returned?

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ){ 

    $dataPOST = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    receiveData($dataPOST);

}


public function receiveData($sentData)
{
$dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->Load($sentData);
    if ($dom->validate()) {

        return true;

}else{
                echo "The XML data was not valid";
                return false;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You can't do that. External API will expect a string in a result and you need to `print` that String in response. Just returning true / false from a function will not work. You need to echo true / false. And yes if their API is expecting only to see either of those values then printing anything extra can render the response invalid.

Instead of

```
 return true;     //This will never get back to their API like this, unless you print it somewhere
```

Write

```
echo "true";
```

Just like

```
 if ($dom->validate()) {
        echo "true";
 }else{
        echo "false";
 }
```

But if you still want to `return`  true or false from here then do the printing at the point where you call the function.

Comment: Thanks I think I was confusing myself but after going back the documentation does not mention boolean (like I thought it had) Thanks for the help. +1 checked.